# Y-axis ticks in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

In highcharts, there are tick marks on the x-axis by default like this on the x-axis (Code Snippet below), but I can't find any way to create tick marks on the y axis. Is this posible?

[image]

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title:{
            text:''
        },
        
        xAxis: {
            gridLineColor: 'transparent',
            title: {
                text: "x"
            },
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            min: -5,
            max: 5,
            tickInterval: 1,
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineColor: 'transparent',
            title: {
                text: "y"
            },
            min: -5,
            max: 5,
            tickInterval: 1,
            lineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            type: "line",
             marker: {
                 enabled: false
             },
            
            data: [
                [-3, 3],
                [-2, 2],
                [-1, 1],
                [0, 0],
                [1, 1],
                [2, 2],
                [3, 3]

            ]
        }]

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 400px; height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use [`tickLength`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickLength) and [`tickWidth`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickWidth):

```
yAxis: {
    tickLength: 10,
    tickWidth: 1
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7ox30pmy/